# gitolite post commit hook to update redmine's repository

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, redmine, gitolite

I currently have a ubuntu server machine which has gitolite and redmine installed. Redmine accesses repository copies which are updated using a cron task.
Having a cron task to pull the updates seems like an overkill is there anyway a gitolite post-commit script could execute a pull as the redmine user.
My current update script looks like this:

```
*/15 * * * * redmine cd /home/redmine/repositories/support && git pull
```

The post-commit script I guess should be similar, how can I give the gitolite user the privileges to execute the pull as the redmine user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have redmine set up to use a seperate repository then the one you push to.  I'd suggest configuring redmine to use your 'origin' repository, rather then having a separate one that you need to deal with updating all the time.

Comment: Does redmine support bare repositories now? I don't use it but last I heard sometime last year it only supported non-bare repositories, and gitolite only works with bare repositories.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly with bare repositories.

Comment: The first time I tried using the bare repositories it didn't work because the privileges weren't set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you must use bare repositories with redmine (for remote repositories).

@user20520 gitolite access permissions are configured with ssh not with local permissions. If you use a remote repository you will have no issues with access controls.